# Android HorizontalScrollView append from right

Tags: android, scrollview

I use this code for append view to HorizontalScrollView.

```
attachView = ...;
lnrCast.addView(attachView);
```

But I want start and append from right.

I dont want append `1, 2, 3, 4, ...`

I want append `... 4, 3, 2, 1`

I use this code, but not rearrange for me:

```
scrollViewCast.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

`RTL` and `gravity` not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
addView(yourView,0);
```

It will always place the view index 0, at the leftmost place.

Comment: Thank you, but if i have 1 item, this item not floating right.

Comment: if you want items at right, `android:grarvity="right|end"` will help

Comment: take a linear layout as the child of `HorizontalScrollView`, with orientation `horizontal`, and with above said `gravity`. instead of adding views to `HorizontalScrollView` add to Linear layout.

Comment: thank you, I changed width to wrap_content and fixed the problem.